# DB refresh & DB migration (MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

I am a newbie to SQL DBA, I wanted to understand the following concepts

1. What is the difference between a Database migration & Database Refresh  in SQL?
2. Suppose we want to migrate a database from one instance to other instance, can we follow the below method

   - Create a new DB in the destination instance with  the same name as the  source instance
   - Refresh destination DB with Source DB, & copy all the user access

Comment: DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question, than sw developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Database migration:**

Moving a database from one server to other usually will do for database upgrades.

**Database Refresh in SQL:**

Overwrite the existing data in the database with other database data using backup files. Usually will refresh production data to UAT or DEV for data/Issue analysis.

Suppose we want to migrate a database from one instance to other instance, can we follow the below method?

Yes you can follow.

If you are using sql server 2012 and above then you can go for contained database options.